# Change Spinner based on another Spinner Selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have string array which contains all the country names and another string array with respective country codes.
I am setting the country names string to spinner.
When I select the item from spinner its respective country code should be set to the spinner. And that item also should change to Code.
Similarly if I select another item its code should be set to spinner and item too. But the first one I selected should change to its original country name.
How should I do this?

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.temp.MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCountry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code

```
package com.example.temp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     final String[] countries = new String[] {"Afghanistan(AF)", "Albania(AX)",
                                              "Algeria(AL)", "American    Samoa(DZ)",
                                              "Andorra(AS)"};

    final String[] countrycodes = new String[]{"AF","AX","AL","DZ","AS"};

    Spinner spinnerCountry;

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinnerCountry=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);

        arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
                                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
        spinnerCountry.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

I can't share my original as I am using it in my application.
But, I am sharing the same code like my original one.
I want to set respective code when I select country from spinner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code of your spinner.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] countries = {"INDIA","DUBAI","KSA"};
        String[] country_code = {"91","971","966"};

        final Spinner spinnerCountry = (Spinner)findViewById (R.id.spinnerCountry);
        final Spinner spinnerCountryCode = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spinnerCountryCode);

        ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);

        ArrayAdapter<String> countryCodeAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,country_code);

        spinnerCountry.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
        spinnerCountryCode.setAdapter(countryCodeAdapter);
        
        spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
                spinnerCountryCode.setSelection(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                
            }
            
        });
        
        spinnerCountryCode.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
                
                spinnerCountry.setSelection(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                
            }
            
        });
```

Here is some code that may fix your problem.

Explanation:

## Assuming you have two spinners R.id.spinnerCountry and R.id.spinnerCountryCode.

As you can see i created two arrays which contains countryName and countryCode respectively.

Work Flow:-

When i select one item in a Spinner then the other spinner loads with another item corresponding to the position.

The code is Self-Explanatory!

Comment: Why do you use "final"?

Comment: @erical sometime i write code like that. that's all. :)

Comment: @erical because you are using the adapters inside the OnItemClickListeners you need to use final

Answer (score 0):

String businesstype_array[] = {"Retail", "Vendor","Agriculture" };

```
public static final String JSON_STRING = "{\"Retail\":[\"General Stores\",\"Clothing\",\"Electronics\",\"Mobile Phones\"],\"Vendor\":[\"Gas agency\",\"newspaper\",\"vendor\",\"milk vendor\",\"laundry\"],\"Agriculture\":[\"lGas agency\",\"lnewspaper\",\"lvendor\",\"lmilk vendor\",\"llaundry\"]}";
```

ArrayAdapter adapter_business = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.singlerow_businesstype_spinner, businesstype_array);
        businesstype.setAdapter(adapter_business);

```
    businesstype.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Log.d("jsonntring", "out tryy");
            try {
                Log.d("jsonntring", "in tryy");


                jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
                Log.d("jsonntring", jsonObject.toString() + "length==" + jsonObject.length());


                JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(businesstype.getSelectedItem().toString());

                Log.d("jsonarray&", jsonarray.toString());

                businesstype__subtype.clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray.length(); j++) {
                    String s = jsonarray.getString(j);

                    businesstype__subtype.add(s);

                    Log.d("jsonarray&", jsonarray.toString());

                }

                ArrayAdapter adapter_sub_business = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.singlerow_businesstype_spinner, businesstype__subtype);
                business_subtype.setAdapter(adapter_sub_business);

            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.d("jsonntring_exce", e.toString());

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: first take an array for first spinner and according to your first array set value inside your json and after change in first spinner set the second one