# Spinner that trigger other spinner

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create an application with two Spinners. When you select one of the items inside the first spinner, the second spinner will get only a few items (depends on which item selected).

For example: in the first spinner I select "Mazda", and then on the second I will be able to see only Mazda's models, not BMW, Ford etc. Can I do something like this?

I tried to create a spinner without items, and set the entries of the spinner on the XML when item selected, but there is no method to do this.

I don't create Lists. I want to create `string-array` resources in my strings.xml, and give that array to the second spinner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Spinner based on another Spinner Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702174/change-spinner-based-on-another-spinner-selection)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is doable and pretty straightforward. Spinners works with the model provider, which in Android it is called `Adapter` pattern. So what you can do is put in your first spinner an adapter that holds all the brands of your cars, and listen on the first spinner for changes using `setOnItemSelectedListener`.

When the item changes, you can create a new adapter instance for the second spinner with the only values that are valid in this case.

Comment: But if i want to add to the second spinner <string-array> from the strings.xml, how can i do this?

Comment: Well if you have all the data hardcoded in the strings it should be easy to decide which is the strings array to take based on the first spinner.

Comment: The first spinner is not the problem, the second spinner is the problem, because the spinner get the strings array with the entries element, but when i want to update the entries on the second spinner, i can't....

Comment: I have been talking about the second spinner. But still not getting your problem. You don't have to update anything, create an instance of another adapter with the data you want to show, doesn't matter where this data comes from, you can create the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. I've organized the sample data in a HashMap but you can do it in your own way.

```
    // hashmap object containing data of spinner1 as 'keys' with relevant  
    // data of spinner2 in List<String> object as 'values'
    final Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("A", Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4"));
    data.put("B", Arrays.asList("4", "5"));
    data.put("C", Arrays.asList("6", "7", "8", "9"));
    data.put("D", Arrays.asList("10", "11", "12"));
    data.put("E", Arrays.asList("13", "14"));

    // obtaining a string array containing keys(data of spinner1) of above hashmap
    final String[] dataSpinner1 = new String[data.keySet().size()];
    data.keySet().toArray(dataSpinner1);

    // initializing an string type, ArrayAdapter for spinner1 
    // you will need to pass activity context, layout for the spinner item and 
    // spinner content(as string array) as arguments to create an array adapter 
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinner1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_layout, dataSpinner1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(spinner1Adapter);

    // setting listner for spinner1 to trigger when an spinner item is being 
    // clicked by the user  
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // obtaining relevant data for spinner2 
            List<String> dataSpinner2 = data.get(dataSpinner1[position]);

            // crating an setting array adapter for spinner2
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinner2Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_layout, dataSpinner2);
            spinner2.setAdapter(spinner2Adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that i am making a multi-language app, it means that i need all the strings to be in the `strings.xml`, and not inside the java code..... That what is cosing me problems....