# Three values with multiple spinner

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Is it possible 3 spinner like this?

from the spinner we have 3 value of drinks:

> if select 1.water > 50mL,100ml,500ml > gallon,bottle
>
> if select 2.coke > 12oz,20oz,35oz > red,blue
>
> if select 3.alcohol drinks > 500mL,1L,1.5L > Light,Brandy

result if i print the value that i want is: "coke 20oz Blue"

**EDIT**

if spinner is selected from water. u will see this

> water▼ 50mL▼ gallon▼

```
       100mL   bottle

       500mL
```

Comment: this does not look like java, and description is very confusing

Comment: its java, i know its confusing but i think that it was possible to get multiple spinner.

Comment: can' understand, please explain more and clean.

Comment: look my edit post it looks like create a 3 final string array

Answer (score 0):

You can create three different spinners for the above three values of drinks  but the last options to select a **red or blue option** from you example after you click on one of the spinner items of 12oz or extra you can be pop up a dialog box with options to select the drink color or other specification and also assign confirmation options to that dialog positive button and vice versa for cancellation by negative button.

But if you want all the options to be selected using spinner only that part might get tricky.Below are the links that might help you if you do not like my upper suggestions

[Spinner that trigger other spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935281/spinner-that-trigger-other-spinner)

[Change Spinner based on another Spinner Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702174/change-spinner-based-on-another-spinner-selection)

you can also use a custom spinner that changes every time on selection until a last option like red or blue is selected.